# Fancybox event when clicked on close

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have the following code that open a fancybox on page load:

```
<script>
window.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.open('#popup_success_strain_add');
});
</script>
```

How can i add now an onclose event that redirects example to google.com?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the [Fancybox callbacks](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs). I suggest `beforeClose` or `afterClose`.

Comment: Thanks but how i insert that in the code above? example

Answer (score 0):

I suggest specifying the element to open in FancyBox by using the `href` option, which "overrides content source link". Then, use the `afterClose` callback to execute a function that performs a JavaScript redirect.

It's not exactly clear in the documentation, but you can use the `href` option to specify a selector string in the same way that you have in your code. Below, I've used that method along with the `afterClose` callback.

Redirection will not be performed from a stack snippet, but I've also included some code that outputs "Redirect" to the page for the sake of demonstration.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fancybox({
    href: '#popup_success_strain_add',
    afterClose: function() {
      $('div#output').text('Redirect.');
      //window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup_success_strain_add">This is the contents.</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

---

### Edit

Another method is to call `fancybox()` on a particular jQuery object (selected element) while specifying the `afterClose` callback, and then trigger "click" to open it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#popup_success_strain_add').fancybox({
    afterClose: function() {
      jQuery('div#output').text('Redirect.');
      //window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
    }
  }).trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup_success_strain_add">This is the contents.</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

---

### Edit

In order to open a new fancybox when the first one closes, I had to add a little delay using `setTimeout`. It seems odd that this is necessary, since the callback is called "*after*Close"... but it seems to work.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fancybox({
    href: '#popup_error_activate',
    afterClose: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $.fancybox.open('#inline1');
      }, 100);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup_error_activate" class="hidden">First Box.</div>
<div id="inline1" class="hidden">Second Box.</div>
```

Comment: Ok cool :) how can i open a new fancybox onclick instead of redirect?

Comment: You mean open another fancybox when the first one is closed? You can execute any code you like, including opening another fancybox, inside the `afterClose` callback.

Comment: I had trouble with that, too. Please see my new edit. You might want to add that requirement to your question so that other people can more easily find it.